# Llamar a una función conociendo su nombre

Tags: python, python-3.x

En Python, ¿cómo se puede llamar a una función conociendo su nombre y sus argumentos?

Por ejemplo, imaginad un fichero functions1.py:

```
def function1():
   print('Hello World')
```

Y otro fichero llamado functions2.py, tal que:

```
def function2(name):
   print('Hello', name)
```

Finalmente, un fichero caller.py, de modo que importe ambas fuentes y permita llamar a la que a ti te apetezca en ese momento, indicado mediante String source (archivo donde se aloja la función), String function (nombre de la función) y una lista de argumentos:

```
import functions1
import functions2

def caller(source, function, args):
    source.function(args)  # Pseudocode

caller('functions2', 'function2', ['Pedro'])
>>> Hola Pedro
```

¿Hay alguna forma de implementar tal función "caller()"?

Comment: Lo genial de Python es que trata a todos como funciones. Puedes hacer lo siguiente `f = my_funcion`, sin los paréntesis lo trata como un objeto, así mismo lo puedes pasar por parámetros sin problemas. Donde `my_funcion` es un método `def my_funcion(): print("hello!")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sí, es posible hacerlo con una mezcla de `importlib` y `getattr`.

### Ejemplo:

Archivo `functions.py` (solo imprime los parámetros):

```
def f1(*args, **kwargs):
    print(args)
    print(kwargs)
```

Archivo `caller.py`:

```
import importlib


def caller(mod, func, *args, **kwargs):
    module = importlib.import_module(mod)
    function = getattr(module, func)
    function(*args, **kwargs)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    caller('functions', 'f1', 10, 20, name='Cesar', language='Python')
```

Ahora, si ejecutamos desde la consola a `caller.py`:

```
$ ls
caller.py  functions.py 
$ python3 caller.py 
(10, 20)
{'language': 'Python', 'name': 'Cesar'}
```

Es sencillo, estamos cargando el módulo `functions` usando `importlib.import_module`. Una vez que tenemos el módulo usamos `getattr` para obtener la función de ese módulo. Finalmente la llamamos como cualquier función normal usando los parámetros pasados.

Comment: ¡Mil gracias! Funciona perfectamente, justo lo que necesitaba.